# Strange values when using Memoization for Grid Traveler problem?

Tags: java, memoization

I'm learning dynamic programming and I've just started with some simple problems. I'm doing a grid traveler problem where you start in the top-left corner of a grid and you can only move left or down. You need to return the amount of unique paths to get from the top-left corner to the bottom-right corner of the grid.

I'm getting some strange return values when I try some bigger grids. For example, when I try (18,18) it goes to -> -1961361076 instead of 2333606220

Can anyone see something wrong with my code?

'''

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        HashMap<String, Integer> memo = new HashMap<>();
        System.out.println(gridTraveler(2,2,memo));
        System.out.println(gridTraveler(18,18,memo));
    }

    public static int gridTraveler(int m, int n, HashMap<String, Integer> memo){

        String key = "" + m + "," + n;
        //base case
        if(m == 1 || n == 1)
            return 1;

        //base case
        if(m == 0 || n == 0)
            return 0;

        if (memo.containsKey(key))
            return memo.get(key);

        //Set value of the key memo[key]
        memo.put(key, gridTraveler(m-1, n, memo) + gridTraveler(m, n-1, memo));

        return memo.get(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: _you can only move left or down_ - did you mean right or down? If so please [edit] and change it

Comment: `-1961361076` probably means that you got a value bigger than In Integer.MAX_VALUE (which is 2147483647). Use double.

Comment: Please close the question as the answer of c0der is correct

Answer (score 1):

This is because the maximum value of an Integer has been reached. When you try to add a value to it, it overflows, and "wraps around" to the negative.

If you change to Long instead of Integer it will work: -

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    HashMap<String, Long> memo = new HashMap<>();
    System.out.println(gridTraveler(2,2,memo));
    System.out.println(gridTraveler(18,18,memo));
}

public static Long gridTraveler(long i, long j, HashMap<String, Long> memo){

    String key = "" + i + "," + j;
    //base case
    if(i == 1 || j == 1)
        return (long) 1;

    //base case
    if(i == 0 || j == 0)
        return (long) 0;

    if (memo.containsKey(key))
        return memo.get(key);

    //Set value of the key memo[key]
    memo.put(key, gridTraveler(i-1, j, memo) + gridTraveler(i, j-1, memo));

    return memo.get(key);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The int datatype in Java is 4 bytes long (32 bits)
Since the format is signed, meaning that the most significant bit of the 32 bits represents the sign of the number (0=positive, 1=negative)
The maximum positive value of int in this case is (2^31)-1 which is 2,147,483,647 which is smaller than your expected output. (this also causes the most significant bit to become 1 and hence explains the negative value)
Therefore, you should use a long which is 8 bytes (64 bits)